# Changing the color of a textbox in VBA (shading off/colour gradient)

Tags: vba, gradient, powerpoint, backcolor

I am trying to **insert an automated summary at the beginning of my PowerPoint presentation** in VBA. (I am fairly new to Visual Basic)

I have found the code that gives me the references, but I can't seem to figure out the colour gradient of one shape.

```
With ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
.Shapes(1).Fill.Visible = msoTrue
.Shapes(1).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(208, 30, 60)
.Shapes(1).Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(97, 18, 30)
.Shapes(1).Fill.TwoColorGradient msoGradientHorizontal, 2
.Shapes(1).Line.Visible = msoFalse
```

The doc on the internet says the method is ForeColor and BackColor, but I can't seem to get it working. I don't understand why the second color is white and not dark red as its RGB code says.

my current template has the title on the side, and vertical, text towards the right side. The textbox is colored with a shading from RGB(208, 30, 60) to RGB(97, 18, 30) linearly with an angle of 270°.

this what is given by the complete VBA code (at the end)
[image]

This what I would like to have (with the numbers as shown in the VBA Slide)
[image: the template I need for that summary]

Complete code:

```
Sub Sommaire()
Dim Diapo As Slide
Dim titre As Shape
Dim petit_titre As Shape
Dim texte_ajout As TextRange
Dim texte_sommaire As TextRange
Dim ligne_sommaire As TextRange
Dim y As Byte
'Si le titre de la première diapo est "Sommaire", elle sera supprimée
'cela permet de relancer la macro autant de fois que l'on souhaite
'sans avoir à supprimer la diapo de sommaire
If ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange = "SOMMAIRE" Then
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Delete
End If
' ajoute une diapo en début de présentation avec
'la disposition de mise en titre n°2 du masque
ActivePresentation.Slides.Add Index:=1, Layout:=ppLayoutText

With ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange = "SOMMAIRE"
.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial Black"
.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 24
.Shapes(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Spacing = 3


.Shapes(1).TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorBottom
.Shapes(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = _
        msoAlignLeft

.Shapes(1).TextFrame2.MarginLeft = 14.1732283465
.Shapes(1).TextFrame2.MarginRight = 14.1732283465
.Shapes(1).TextFrame2.MarginTop = 14.1732283465
.Shapes(1).TextFrame2.MarginBottom = 28.3464566929
.Shapes(1).TextFrame2.WordWrap = msoTrue
.Shapes(1).TextFrame.Orientation = msoTextOrientationUpward
.Shapes(1).Left = 0 * 72
.Shapes(1).Top = 0 * 72
.Shapes(1).Height = ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight
.Shapes(1).Width = 0.975 * 72

.Shapes(1).Fill.Visible = msoTrue
.Shapes(1).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(208, 30, 60)
.Shapes(1).Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(97, 18, 30)
.Shapes(1).Fill.TwoColorGradient msoGradientHorizontal, 2
.Shapes(1).Line.Visible = msoFalse

.Shapes(1).Shadow.Type = msoShadow25
.Shapes(1).Shadow.Visible = msoTrue
.Shapes(1).Shadow.Style = msoShadowStyleInnerShadow
.Shapes(1).Shadow.Blur = 5
.Shapes(1).Shadow.OffsetX = 3.9993907806
.Shapes(1).Shadow.OffsetY = -0.0698096257
.Shapes(1).Shadow.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(52, 9, 16)
.Shapes(1).Shadow.Transparency = 0.5


Set texte_ajout = .Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange
End With

With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes _
     .AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 1.5275 * 72, 32.7, 180, 29.1)
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Sommaire"
    .TextFrame.MarginBottom = 10
    .TextFrame.MarginLeft = 10
    .TextFrame.MarginRight = 10
    .TextFrame.MarginTop = 10
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial Black"
    .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 18
    .TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
        .TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = _
        msoAlignLeft
    .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
    .Line.Visible = msoFalse
    .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 1).Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(208, 30, 60)
    .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(2, 7).Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(39, 39, 39)
    .Shadow.Visible = msoFalse

    End With







'boucle sur toutes les diapos à partir de la 2e
For y = 2 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
Set Diapo = ActivePresentation.Slides(y)
'si la diapo a un titre
If Diapo.Shapes.HasTitle Then
Set titre = Diapo.Shapes.Title
texte_ajout = texte_ajout & Format(y, "0 - ") & titre.TextFrame. _
TextRange.Text & Chr(13) & vbCrLf
End If
Next y
'ajout de liens aux items du sommaire
Set texte_sommaire = _
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange
texte_sommaire.Font.Size = 20
texte_sommaire.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(39, 39, 39)

With ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(2)
.Left = 1.5275 * 72
.Top = 1.9 * 72
End With

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Bonjour compatriote. I got this using the Object Browser (press F2 in VBEditor) : `ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(2).TextFrame.Orientation = msoTextOrientationVertical` or `msoTextOrientationVerticalFarEast` (all constants are listed in ` msoTextOrientation`)

Comment: While "bidouiller" with the code, I found that orientation command, and I am using it with `msoTextOrientationUpward` which gives me the orientation I wanted, but I get a big square shape. 
For the color, I am trying to use excel and 'reccord a macro' to get the code I want. Do you know how I can get the textbox to fit to the height of the slides? - Thank you very much

Comment: Check in PowerPoint VBE the object browser (press F2) and take a look into the Slide class and in Shape class, but I guess those two have `Height` and `Width` properties, so i think something like this would be useful : `Shapes(2).height = Slides(1).height`

Comment: @R3uK I used `.Shapes(1).Height = ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight` to get the right height. I tried to post a picture of where I am at now, I have the position right, I just have the spacing, and the coloring off of the side box. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I picked that from Excel macro recorder, as Shapes and most of the objects still have a lot of commons parts between Office applications.

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 1")).Select
With Selection.ShapeRange
    With .Fill
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .BackColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 1)
        .TwoColorGradient msoGradientHorizontal, 1
        .RotateWithObject = msoTrue
        .Visible = msoTrue
    End With
    With .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .Spacing = 1.6
    End With
End With
```

You only need to "attach" (replace the `Selection`) it to your textbox, but I think you can handle that. I'll edit my answer to include all pointers I gave you in comments too.

Comment: Hi, that was the method I used too. I defined the box after starting to record a macro. I switched the order of the `twocolorgradient` so it is now before `forecolor` and `backcolor` (it occurred to me that the order might have an importance) and I get exactly what I wanted. But thank you.

Comment: Ok, glad you found a way to do it! I'll improve my answer later, but just for clarification, I just have a question about the second parameter of the `TwoColorGradient` method. You proposed a correction with `2` as `Gradient`, did you understand the meaning of that parameter? I'm still perplex about this one (Not dramatic)

Comment: It's the position of the gradient. 2 has the gradient around the top middle. 3 has the gradient around the middle. And 1 has the gradient around the bottom middle. In my case, 2 makes the red go darker from bottom to top, and 1 is the other way around.

Comment: Ok, thx for your explanation! ;)
Bonne journée! (btw could you upvote my answer, I'm working on my refiner badge and it would help me :) )

Comment: No problemo :) no pb, pas de soucis! Done!